# Use maven repositories in native Wicket project

Tags: java, maven, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, wicket

we are trying to implement a web application for "Database Managment Systems" lecture.

We have used native wicket. (Not maven wicket repo, because i don't have a pom.xml file)

I want to use the Wicket Bootstrap DatePicker in the project. (http://agilecoders.de/demo/datepicker)

Can i use this datepicker extension in my project?

I downloaded the wicket bootstrap from github. (github(dot)com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/)

I found the sample file html/java codes. It imports these:

```
import de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.block.Code;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.button.BootstrapButton;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.button.Buttons;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.extensions.markup.html.bootstrap.form.DateTextField;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.extensions.markup.html.bootstrap.form.DateTextFieldConfig;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.samples.components.basecss.DatePickerModal;
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount.MountPath;
```

When i import the sources which start with "de.agilecoder...." Eclipse says "The import de cannot be resolved"

How can i solve this problem?

I dont want to use wicket's default datepicker, because it is hard to pick birthday from it.

I hope, i can expres myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Maven in your project, there are two things you can do:

1. Use Maven to build the Wicket Bootstrap project: Download the project archive file (like you already did), download Maven and run `mvn package` in the Wicket Bootstrap project directory with a pom.xml file. This will result in bunch of "jar" files (under "subproject-name/target" directory) which you can add as dependencies to your project.
2. Just go to the "bootstrap-extensions/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/extensions/markup/html/bootstrap/form" Direcotry, copy the "DateTextField.java" File to your project (in appropriate package "de.agilecoders.wicket.extensions.markup.html.bootstrap.form") and resolve all dependencies for this class in similar way. But this sounds like really hard work... You could also learn Maven in the same time ;)